# Which Ruby XML library would you recommend for a 2.4MB XML file?

Tags: xml, ruby

I have a 2.4 MB XML file, an export from Microsoft Project (hey I'm the victim here!) from which I am requested to extract certain details for re-presentation. Ignoring the intelligence or otherwise of the request, which library should I try first from a Ruby perspective?

I'm aware of the following (in no particular order):

- [REXML](http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/)
- [Chilkat Ruby XML library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ruby-xml.asp)
- [hpricot XML](http://code.whytheluckystiff.net/hpricot/wiki/HpricotXML)
- [libXML](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/)

I'd prefer something packaged as a Ruby gem, which I suspect the Chilkat library is not.

Performance isn't a major issue - I don't expect the thing to need to run more than once a day (once a week is more likely). I'm more interested in something that's as easy to use as anything XML-related is able to get.

EDIT: I tried the gemified ones:

hpricot is, by a country mile, easiest. For example, to extract the content of the SaveVersion tag in this XML (saved in a file called, say 'test.xml')

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/project">
    <SaveVersion>12</SaveVersion>
</Project>
```

takes something like this:

```
doc = Hpricot.XML(open('test.xml'))
version = (doc/:Project/:SaveVersion).first.inner_html
```

hpricot seems to be relatively unconcerned with namespaces, which in this example is fine: there's only one, but would potentially be a problem with a complex document. Since hpricot is also very slow, I rather imagine this would be a problem that solves itself.

libxml-ruby is an order of magnitude faster, understands namespaces (it took me a good couple of hours to figure this out) and is altogether much closer to the XML metal - XPath queries and all the other stuff are in there. This is not necessarily a Good Thing if, like me, you open up an XML document only under conditions of extreme duress. The helper module was mostly helpful in providing examples of how to handle a default namespace effectively. This is roughly what I ended up with (I'm not in any way asserting its beauty, correctness or other value, it's just where I am right now):

```
xml_parser = XML::Parser.new
xml_parser.string = File.read(path)
doc = xml_parser.parse
@root = doc.root
@scopes = { :in_node => '', :in_root => '/', :in_doc => '//' }
@ns_prefix = 'p'
@ns = "#{@ns_prefix}:#{@root.namespace[0].href}"
version = @root.find_first(xpath_qry("Project/SaveVersion", :in_root), @ns).content.to_i

def xpath_qry(tags, scope = :in_node)
  "#{@scopes[scope]}" + tags.split(/\//).collect{ |tag| "#{@ns_prefix}:#{tag}"}.join('/')
end
```

I'm still debating the pros and cons: libxml for its extra rigour, hpricot for the sheer style of _why's code.

EDIT again, somewhat later: I discovered HappyMapper ('gem install happymapper') which is hugely promising, if still at an early stage. It's declarative and mostly works, although I have spotted a couple of edge cases that I don't have fixes for yet. It lets you do stuff like this, which parses my Google Reader OPML:

```
module OPML
  class Outline
    include HappyMapper
    tag 'outline'
    attribute :title, String
    attribute :text, String
    attribute :type, String
    attribute :xmlUrl, String
    attribute :htmlUrl, String
    has_many :outlines, Outline
  end
end

xml_string = File.read("google-reader-subscriptions.xml")

sections = OPML::Outline.parse(xml_string)
```

I already love it, even though it's not perfect yet.

Comment: Oh noes!  A 2.4 mb XML file!  THE HORROR!

Comment: Well, I thought the answer might be different if it was 2.4 GB... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hpricot](http://code.whytheluckystiff.net/hpricot/wiki/HpricotBasics) is probably the best tool for you -- it is easy to use and should handle 2mg file with no problem.

Speedwise libxml should be the best. I used libxml2 binding for python few months ago (at that moment rb-libxml was stale). Streaming interface worked the best for me
(LibXML::XML::Reader in ruby gem). It allows to process file while it is downloading, is a bit more userfriendly than SAX and allowed me to load data from 30mb xml file from internet to a MySQL database in a little more than a minute.

Comment: These days I'd recommend [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) over Hpricot. In my experience it's been a lot more stable and is very fully featured and well maintained.

Comment: Yes I agree, Nokogiri is the way to go these days

Answer (score 4):

Nokogiri wraps libxml2 and libxslt with a clean, Rubyish API that supports namespaces, XPath and CSS3 queries. Fast, too.
http://nokogiri.org/

Comment: Note, due to underlying dependencies, it only supports XPATH 1.0