# Libxml Ruby : Do I need to manually garbage collect node sets returned by doucment#find?

Tags: ruby, libxml-ruby

The documentation for LibXML::XML::Document#find mentions that following code style needs to be used to avoid seg faults:

```
nodes = doc.find('/header')
nodes.each do |node|
  ... do stuff ...
end
```

Is this all I need to do? Below the example code box there is some commented out code:

```
# nodes = nil # GC.start
```

Do I need to include this code as well to be sure of avoiding a seg fault? I wouldn't have thought that the style shown in the first block of code would help much with reference problems. I tried it without the commented out code and have had no problems after processing a large number of files but maybe it's something that crops up under rare circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

No. The commented-out code looks like the author was worried about a problem with the interaction with the GC and as the follow up mentions

> When the process terminates, Ruby sometimes frees the document object 
>   before the nodes object, thereby causing a segmentation fault.
>
> Before anyone asks, the nodes class has a mark function that tells Ruby 
>   that it is dependent on the document.  The mark function works fine, and 
>   if the following two lines of code are added to the end of the test code 
>   all is well:
>
> nodes = nil
>
> GC.start

**I wouldn't worry about it too much because:**

(a) The problem refers to the library in 2008

(b) Many of us have used LibXML and apart from it being a pain to use, it is fast and stable so the author must have sorted out his problems.

If you are looking for alternatives, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126337/which-ruby-xml-library-would-you-recommend-for-a-2-4mb-xml-file)

Chris

Comment: I found this post http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/17694 (by the author of libxml-ruby I guess) which indicates that at some point there was a problem with not being able to predict the order in which ruby objects are destroyed at script termination. Maybe this is solved but the documentation libxml-ruby is unclear. Perhaps I should contact the author. I'm aware of the alternatives and know that some of them provide a more friendly idiomatic ruby interface. I'm interested in libxml because it's fast and fairly complete, at minimum I need schema validation and xpath.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect that (thanks). Advice still stands, LibXML is pretty well tested but other (possibly better supported) alternatives exist.